# ActiveRecord search criteria

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models

Employee

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_company_segments
  has_many :company_segments, :through => :employee_company_segments
end
```

Company Segment

```
class CompanySegment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_company_segments
  has_many :employees, :through => :employee_company_segments
end
```

and an intersection, EmployeeCompanySegment

```
class EmployeeCompanySegment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :company_segment   
end
```

This all works fine.

In addition to this, there is a company_segment_id on the employee. The concept is that each employee belongs to a company segment. We then have certain employees that can view all the employees in one or more segments. So what I am looking for, I think, is a scope or method on the employee that allows me to do this...

EmployeeA has two EmployeeCompanySegment records, one with a company_segment_id of 1 and another with a company_segment_id of 2. If there are ten employees that have a company_segment_id or 1 or 2 on their record, EmployeeA should be able to see all ten.

another way of thinking about it

For employeeA, select all the employees that have a company_segment_id on their record that is the same as the company_segment_id on one of the EmployeeCompanySegment records that have an employee_id that matches employeeA.

Can anyone help?

I tried passing in an array like this but just returns an empty array

```
def visible_employees
  Employee.where(:company_segment_id => [EmployeeCompanySegment.all.collect { |x| x.id}])
end
```

Then I corrected it to something more sensible....

```
def visible_employees
  Employee.where(:company_segment_id => [EmployeeCompanySegment.all.collect { |x| x.company_segment_id}])
end
```

just testing now...

Final edit...

```
def visible_employees
  Employee.where(:company_segment_id => [EmployeeCompanySegment.where(:employee_id => self.id).collect { |x| x.company_segment_id}])
end
```

and this works. thanks for listening :)

Comment: have you looked at a `has_and_belongs_to_many` association? http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: Yes, but not sure how that helps. Isn't that just a slightly less verbose method of describing the associations?